# Spring Boot, The object is not deleted eventhough delete command is being executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have customers and books in my table. When a customer is deleted I also want book's availability to be set to available. When I only execute the code without first 3 lines of the method(setting availability to the available) it works perfectly fine and deletes the customer object. But when I add those lines to set books available then nothing happens and customer object stays without any removal.

```
@GetMapping("/customers/delete/{id}")
public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") int theId, Model model){
    Customer c1 = CustomerService.getSingleCustomer(theId).get();
    for(int i=0;i<c1.getRentedBooks().size();i++){
        c1.getRentedBooks().get(i).availability="Available";
    }
   

    CustomerService.delete(theId);
    return "redirect:/customer/listofcustomers";
}
```

Comment: For starters this code needs to be in a service *not* in a controller. Second do you have a bi-directional relationship between book and customer? If so the update on book will re-instate the customer.

Comment: I get the idea that any update will re-instate the customer but the thing is I do update operations before deleting the customer. So in my perspective nothing should change considering the order of the execution. What is the correct way of doing what I aimed for. Thank you in advance for your comment

Comment: Everything is flushed at once instead of single operations. What you should do is set the customer to null in the books, change the status and delete the user. And as stated this code should be in service method **not** a controller method. YOur controller should call that transactional service method.

Comment: Is `CustomerService` a class or a poor variable identifier?? ;(;(;(

Comment: Hey Deinum, The problem was I never set Book's customer attribute to null. I have moved my code to service method and set customer to null while deletion as you have told me. It worked like a charm. Thanks for taking your time and helping me out

Answer (score 1):

If field availability in Book class is private, use:

```
c1.getRentedBooks().get(i).setAvailability("Available");
```